# PowerShell: Export csv files after using Group-Object

Tags: powershell, csv, export-csv

I've just started learning PowerQuery and my objective is to split a large csv file into smaller csv files based on column value. I have seen solutions which work well for small files but even when i use PowerShell instead of the ISE it still takes three minutes to split a file with 500K lines.
I have tried using Group-object which implicitly create a hash table and I can list the groups

```
Import-csv ./myfile.csv | Group-Object -Property Region | Select-Object Group
```

but now I would like to loop over the group objects and pipe them to Export-CSV using the group name as the file name.

Comment: Please take a moment and read the following help topic before you proceed: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: demo data is here http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/ and when i list the output the website complains about syntax errors in the code.

Comment: Did you read the help topic? ;-)  You should post along with your question all code needed to understand what you're doing (formated as code), some (a few lines) sanitized example data if needed (formated as code as well), together with error messages you get, if there are some and maybe some examples of the results you expect. Try to make it as easy as possible for the people willing to help you. We cannot see your screen and we cannot read your mind. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Import-Csv ./myfile.csv | Group-Object Region | ForEach {

$_.Group | Export-Csv ('./' + $_.Name + '.csv') -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Took 46 seconds to split one of the "500.000 Sales Records" file from richard kl's url.

Comment: Just to add that thanks to your assistance I now know how to reference items within a hash table and can see the names of the object properties making it much easier to work out my own solutions.